How to play multi-note Appogiaturas and Acciaccaturas
Correct me if I'm wrong but from my knowledge appogiaturas begin on the beat and acciaccaturas begin before the beat.
How then exactly is one supposed to play this 3-note appogiatura (or any-note appogiatura in any piece for that matter) in Rondo alla Turca? From what I hear and see other people play, the appogiatura here is played before the beat and then the A note and C# octave are played on the beat. My initial thought was since this is an appogiatura the first note of the appogiatura and the C# octave above would be played on the beat brushing up to the A note.
So my question is how are you supposed to play multi-note appogiaturas (in this piece and in general) and how would it be different if it were an acciaccatura?


I’ve revised my answer, which was wrong initially.

Yes, that is correct. The top is the treble clef and the bottom is the bass.

@ToddWilcox given the key signatures, there's no other possibility.

In general, it depends on the style of the piece and sometimes the specific composer. However, in the case of Mozart's Rondo alla Turca, it should be initiated before the beat. The appogiaturas in the piece are imitations of percussion instruments, which, of course, would play on the beat, but to get the proper effect on piano, the need to start a bit early.

Even though they are notated without the slash, these aren't the 'suspension' type of appogiatura.  Don't try to analyse them too closely or look for a 'rule'.   It's a style sort of thing.  In a Chopin Ballade  these sort of gracenotes might be played quite lingeringly.  In this case I'd suggest they're more like a drum 'ruff', to be played fast and before the beat.
Listen to some performances.  This pianist hardly spreads them at all.
https://fb.watch/vHgcSB8CFy/
This one takes a lot more time over them, almost to the point of pausing the tempo.



My preference would be for something in between.
